# Regular expression to not match file two file types in Bash

Tags: linux, bash

I'm trying to do a list in bash of files that are not `.html` or `.js`

I've tired both of the following methods but neither work?

```
ls !(*.html|*.js)


ls | grep -v '\.(html|js)$'
```

Comment: Please note that the what you specify in shell in your first example is not a regular expression but wildcards.

Comment: Generally, parsing `ls` is considered unsafe: mywiki.wooledge.org/ParsingLs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `extended-regexp` with the `-E` option:

```
ls | grep -E -v '\.(html|js)$'
```

Comment: I'd also use `ls -1` to list the files in a single column.

Comment: @Blender" `ls` defaults to single-column when its output isn't to a terminal (e.g. when it's a pipe), so the `-1` isn't necessary. Which is not to say that it's a bad idea, just not a necessary one.

Answer (score 2):

There's yet another way to do it. bash has an option for extended glob patterns:

```
shopt -s extglob
ls !(*.html|*.js)
```

(Note that this is still a glob pattern, *not* a regular expression -- for example, `*` means "any string", not "zero or more of the preceding thing").

Comment: can also be written as `*.!(html|js)`

Comment: @glennjackman: not quite; that won't match files that don't have an extension at all, and *will* match files like "foo.bar.html".

Answer (score 1):

If your version of `ls` supports the `-I` flag:

```
ls -I *.js -I *.html
```

From the man page:

```
-I, --ignore=PATTERN
       do not list implied entries matching shell PATTERN
```

---

Otherwise, use `find`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f ! \( -name "*.html" -o -name "*.js" \)
```

For formatting add:

```
 -printf "%f\n"
```

If the filenames need to be piped, you only need to change the `printf()` statement:

```
-printf '%f\0' | xargs -0 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

The `-I` flag can filter `ls` output:

```
ls -I '*.html' -I '*.js'
```

or

```
ls | grep -v -e '\.html' -e '\.js'
```

From the man page:

```
 -e PATTERN, --regexp=PATTERN
              Use PATTERN as the pattern; useful to protect patterns beginning with -.
```